# How to display Json data in Nativescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nativescript

I want to display in page all value. I have this JSON.

```
    res {
       "StatusCode": 0,
       "StatusMessage": "OK",
       "StatusDescription": [
         {
           "sensors": [
             {
               "serial": "sensor1",
               "id": "1"
             },
   {
               "serial": "sensor2",
               "id": "2"
             },
             {
               "serial": "sensor3",
               "id": "3"
             }
           ],
           "HBP_id": "12",
           "HB_id": "123",
          "serial_number": "hb1",
          "note": "test"
        }
       ]
     }
```

I want to display in Nativescript:

```
serial_number: hb1
sensors : sensor1
```

I tried this code, but with this I can show only serial_number:

```
   <StackLayout class="page">
        <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
             <ng-template let-item="item">
                 <Label [text]="item.serial_number"
                  class="list-group-item"></Label>
             </ng-template>
        </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
```

Please, can you ask me any idea how to display and serial?

Thank you

Solution:

```
<ListView [items]="items" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
                    <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
                        <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
                            <Label [text]="item.serial_number"></Label>
                            <Label *ngFor="let subItem of item?.sensors" [text]="subItem.serial"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ng-template>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Try this.  `item.sensors[0]?.serial`

Comment: Is sensors have multiple object in an array?????

Comment: Yes, are some sensors. I tried this, `item.sensors?.serial` show nothing, and `item.sensors[0]?.serial`  show error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Can you post the error as well and post the updated code????

Comment: Try this `item?.sensors[0]?.serial` in your html

Comment: System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I think you should take another ng-template inside ng-template for binding sensors??

Comment: So, I have more sensors, like in json. When I tried like this `item?.sensors[0]?.serial` I can show only first `"serial": "sensor1"`, also, I want to show In serial in sensors and item.serial_number

Comment: You need to use nested ng-template in your html

Comment: Can you write an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try nested `<ng-template>`

```
<StackLayout class="page">
    <ListView [items]="items" class="list-group">
         <ng-template let-item="item">
             <Label [text]="item.serial_number"
              class="list-group-item"></Label>
             <ng-template *ngFor="let subItem of item?.sensors">
                  <Label [text]="subItem.serial"
                      class="list-group-item"></Label>
             </ng-template>
         </ng-template>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

If you don't want to use `ngFor` then use `let-subItem="item?.sensors"`.

This could be help you!!